# Hi i tried to implement onclick action in my recyclerview ,but its not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> Hi i tried to do onclick in my recycler view, before implementing the onclick in my my original project,i created dummy project for testing the recycler view and its clock.My dummy project is working perfect ,i can click the recycler view and then can display the details in to an another activity.But i used the same code in my original project, but i tried to click the items on the recycler view ,there is no response.And i noticed an error in my origional project 
>   log cat:/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
>   My dummy project code is

```
public class RVAdapter
    extendsRecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {     public
    List<Person> persons= Collections.emptyList(); //     private
    Context mContext;  private LayoutInflater inflater;



            ImageLoader mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

            private static Context context;


            public RVAdapter(Context context, List<Person> persons) {
                this.persons = persons;
                  this.context = context;
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            }

            @Override
            public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,
        parent, false);
                PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);


                return pvh;
            }

            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int postions) {

                Person person = persons.get(postions);
                holder.phoneName.setText(person.getKitchen_accesries());
                holder.phonePrice.setText(person.getKitchen_price());
                holder.itemView.setTag(person);

           if (mImageLoader == null)
                   mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
              holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(person.getThumbnail(), mImageLoader);


            }


            @Override
            public int getItemCount() {
                if (persons != null) {
                    return persons.size();
                }
                return 0;
            }


            @Override
            public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
                super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
            }

            public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView .ViewHolder
                    implements View
                    .OnClickListener  {
                CardView cv;
                TextView phoneName;
                TextView phonePrice;
                public List<Person> persons;


                NetworkImageView thumbnail;

                PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);

                    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
                    phoneName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_name);
                    phonePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_price);
                    thumbnail = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                    itemView.setOnClickListener(this); //
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view ) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context,ViewActivity.class);

                    Person person =(Person)view.getTag();

                    String strUrl= person.getThumbnail();
                    String product_name=person.getKitchen_accesries();
                    String product_price=person.getKitchen_price();
                    intent.putExtra("TV",product_name);
                    intent.putExtra("Price",product_price);
                    intent.putExtra("Image",strUrl);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }


            }


        }
```

**My Original project code is :**

```
        public class Mobile_recycle_Adapter extends        RecyclerView.
Adapter   <Mobile_recycle_Adapter.PersonViewHolder>   {
                List<Details> mobile_details= Collections.emptyList();
                private LayoutInflater inflater;
                 private static Context context;

    ImageLoader mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


 public Mobile_recycle_Adapter( Context context,List<Details>
mobile_details) {
        this.mobile_details = mobile_details;
     this.context = context;
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview,
parent, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder holder, int i) {

         Details mob_details=mobile_details.get(i);
        holder.phoneName.setText(mob_details.getPhone_name());
        holder.phonePrice.setText(mob_details.getPhone_price());


//
        if (mImageLoader == null)
            mImageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        holder.thumbnail.setImageUrl(mob_details.getPhone_image(), mImageLoader);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mobile_details != null) {
            return mobile_details.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }



    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View
            .OnClickListener{
        CardView cv;
        TextView phoneName;
        TextView phonePrice;
      NetworkImageView thumbnail;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            phoneName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_name);
            phonePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_price);
            thumbnail=(NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Details_view.class);

            Details person =(Details)view.getTag();

            String strUrl= person.getPhone_image();
            String product_name=person.getPhone_name();
            String product_price=person.getPhone_price();
            intent.putExtra("Phone",product_name);
            intent.putExtra("Price",product_price);
            intent.putExtra("Image",strUrl);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: hi Harshad do you have any solution for my pblm?

Comment: change itemView.setOnClickListener(this); in ur code to cv.setOnClickListener(this);  and in onclick method make a check ..... @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(v == cv)
            {
             //do what u want here
            }}

Comment: let me try and will catch u

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to write `itemView.setOnClickListener(this);` in your orignal project code,

you should add this line to your `PersonViewHolder()` constructor as you did in your dummy project

Comment: i added that but there is no response ,phonePrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_price);
            thumbnail=(NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewB

Comment: as a workaround can you try to set that in `onBindViewHolder()` like this, `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {};`

Comment: Also your `Activity` code where you are assigning adapter to `RecyclerView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93583/discussion-between-swaroop-and-satyen-udeshi).

Answer (score 0):

add `cv.setOnClickListener(this);` in ur constructor `PersonViewHolder`